# FormData Inserting Extra TExt

Tags: javascript, ajax, multipartform-data

I'm using form data in Javascript to send my inputs to the server but I noticed something funky.  In Firefox and Chrome it sends back extra text along with the data and adds it to the original value. Here is an example of what chrome outputs

------WebKitFormBoundaryq5GElQTvd3mbU5qE--

Here is my code. I am doing a PUT request.

```
var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('user','tester');
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

                req.onload=function(e){
                    console.log(this)
                }

                req.open('PUT','http://localhost/site_template/create_file.php',true);
                req.send(formData);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the random string after a WebKitFormBoundary do \ mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671138/what-does-the-random-string-after-a-webkitformboundary-do-mean)

Comment: Say it's a repeat, but the link provided no answer on how to deal with it

Comment: What is your question exactly? This is standard browser behavior, as far as I can see.

Comment: How do you deal with the extra text server side. Obviously it's no good to store it along with the content that's needed