# Getting POST parameters not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restify

I'm trying to send a post parameter (key: test, value: somevlaue) using PostMan using **restify** framework. For this I've used 2 methods and both are not working:

1st one shows this error:

```
{
  "code": "InternalError",
  "message": "Cannot read property 'test' of undefined"
}
```

2nd one (commented) shows only Error: someerror

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var restify=require('restify');
var fs=require('fs');
var qs = require('querystring');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var controllers = {};

var server=restify.createServer();

server.post("/get", function(req, res, next){
    res.send({value: req.body.test,
     error: "someerror"});

    //**********METHOD TWO*********************

/*
     if (req.method == 'POST') {
         var body = '';

         req.on('data', function (data) {
             body += data;
         });

         req.on('end', function () {
             var post = qs.parse(body);
             res.send({
                 Data: post.test,
                 Error: "Someerror"
             });
         });
     }
     */

});
server.listen(8081, function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);
    else
        console.log('App is ready at : ' + 8081);
});
```

Comment: in your post code have you checked the data. `req`, `req.body` and `req.body.test`? Are they all undefined or do they return some values?

Comment: So how are you making the post to it?

Comment: When checked, req is shown as a long URL type thing (I don't know what is it), and req.body is [object Object]

Comment: @epascarello I'm giving Form params to it using PostMan

Comment: I do not use resitify, but don;t you need something like `server.use(restify.bodyParser());`

Comment: var post is also shown as [object Object]

Comment: @epascarello Now I'm getting this error: {
  "code": "InvalidContent",
  "message": "Invalid JSON: Unexpected number"
}

Comment: "'m trying to send a post parameter (key: test, value: somevlaue) using PostMan — How have you configured it? What content-type are you sending?

Comment: req.params takes parameters only from URL. What if I have to insert a lot of items into database? I will have to enter them in a URL which is not good. So I'm not using req.params @Craicerjack What you say?

Comment: I say okay. probably a good idea not too

Comment: @Quentin content-type: application/json and I'm sending value from "form-data" option. Is it okay?

Comment: @Craicerjack I think I'm doing something wrong. If corrected, my methods would work. But I don't know what's wrong. I guess it has something to do with bodyParser

Comment: under your `server` and before your route try adding the following line `server.use(restify.bodyParser({ mapParams: false })); `

Comment: :( Now it isn't showing any resposne. The page is not loading.

Comment: My problem is solved by following answer. But I don't understand why Method 2 is not working? Does anybody have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have your `bodyparser` set up incorrectly. 
According to [the docs](http://restify.com/#Bundled-Plugins) under the body parser section you set up the parser in this manner:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser({
    maxBodySize: 0,
    mapParams: true,
    mapFiles: false,
    .....
 }));
```

The default is to map the data to `req.params` but you can change this and map it to `req.body` by setting the `mapParams` option to `false`

> **BodyParser**
>
> Blocks your chain on reading and parsing the HTTP request body.
>   Switches on Content-Type and does the appropriate logic. 
>   application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and
>   multipart/form-data are currently supported.

Comment: Sorry, the page is not loading now.

Comment: did you remove `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` and are you getting any errors

Comment: I haven't removed it. Shall I remove it?

Comment: Im not sure but I would think so, it looks like restify has its own `bodyParser`. Are you following a tutorial setting this up?

Comment: Getting this now for `req.body` : `{
  "value": "------WebKitFormBoundary328lp0XGU1NVXSRY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\nsdaff\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary328lp0XGU1NVXSRY--\r\n",
  "error": "someerror"
}`

Comment: You can see there's value in this thing but it is messed up

Comment: Hey looks like I got it. When I changed it to x-www-form-url thing, I got the response I wanted.

Comment: switch `mapParams` back to true and then try and access `req.params` and `req.params.test`

Comment: No. I want req.body only. It's fine. Now this became possible by using Method 1 (see question detail). Could you please tell why the Method 2 is not working? Am I doing it in wrong way?

Comment: Regarding the `WebKitFormBoundary` see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671138/what-does-the-random-string-after-a-webkitformboundary-do-mean

Comment: I would think because your trying to use `querystring` on a `POST` request. I would also recommend giving the restify API documentation a good read. Youre adding in packages (querystring, bodyparser) that look like they are already contained in `restify`

Comment: Thank you but what do you say about my last comment? Do you know about it?

Comment: No, when I remove qs, it shows error qs is not defined.

Comment: Yeah my point was not to use `qs` at all. Why do you want to use method 2 at all?

Answer (score 1):

With restify ^7.7.0, you don't have to require('body-parser') any more. Just use restify.plugins.bodyParser():

```
var server = restify.createServer()
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`${server.name} listening ${server.url}`))
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser()) // can parse Content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
server.post('/your_url', your_handler_func)
```